# Map kit route in ios7

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I want to show a route between 2 points on the map in ios7.
So i have the source point ,but i can't understand how to input a destination with coordinates:

```
  MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    request.source = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
    request.destination = _destination;  // HERE I WANT TO ADD COORDINATES.
```

Than i have some location:

CLLocation *gotopoint = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:100.09361  longitude:33.85482];

How to i set this point to the destination ?

Thanks

Comment: I assume those latitude numbers are just dummy text in the question because a latitude of 100.xxx or 132.xxx is invalid (must be from -90 to +90).

Answer (score 1):

got it :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D _srcCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(132.09361,134.854);
    MKPlacemark *_srcMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:_srcCoord addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *gotopoint= [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:_srcMark];
```